# How to smoothly increase / decrease in zoom in and zoom out using ffmpeg in zoompan?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, screen-recording

I have created a new web application which functions as a screen recording tool.

For instance, users can initiate the recording process, and once complete, they can proceed to the editing panel. Within the editing panel, there are various options available such as video zooming in and out based on duration, X and Y coordinates, etc.

As a backend developer, I have utilized the FFmpeg library in Node.js. Although I have successfully implemented some of the zoom in and out functionalities, I am experiencing some difficulty in achieving smooth transitions.

This is the command which I used for output video.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf " zoompan=z='if(between(in_time,0,04),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/(zoom+0.01)/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',zoompan=z='if(between(in_time,05,09),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/(zoom+0.01)/50)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/1)',zoompan=z='if(between(in_time,11,15),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/50-(iw/(zoom+0.01)/10)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)' ,zoompan=z='if(between(in_time,18,20),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/(zoom+0.01)/1)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/50)' ,zoompan=z='if(between(in_time,22,25),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/30-(iw/(zoom+0.01)/50)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/50)', zoompan=z='if(between(in_time,27,30),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/(zoom+0.01)/2)':y='ih/50-(ih/zoom/30)'" output.mp4

Please find below the input video and the output video which I have processed:

Input video: https://fidi-screen-records.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/sam.mp4

Output video: https://fidi-screen-records.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/finalVideos/1678798893088_24d034f7469b5e79_x3JT9w.mp4

Ideally, I would like to achieve an output similar to the following video:

Expected output video:  https://twitter.com/mickeyxfriedman/status/1631360293564715008?s=46&t=LlV2Tx37C24-F4xCMdZuaA

Could you help me to do smooth zoom in and out transition like the expected video which I shared?
Do I need to add any packages? or Do I have to make any changes in my coding?

Comment: cant look twitter, maybe, you need to replace `,2,1` with something like this: `,min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.05,2),min(max(zoom,pzoom)-0.05,2)`

Comment: Thank you so much its working fine for zoom in. Can you suggest me a solution for zoom out